# Multimedia Timer limitations or why it stops firing randomly

Tags: c#, timer, callback, multimedia

I have a program that responds to an event X. I need to react to this event within ms and do a job a few times. This can take up to 30''. Therefore, I created a class which I ping once I receive the event and I launch a multimedia timer.
This can be called several times but usually up to 6 timers at the same time at most. My application starts great, NEVER throws warnings/exceptions, I can't see memory leaks... But randomly, **if my application has processed quite a few events, it stops firing the multimedia timers. I can see how it is called but it never calls the callback function anymore. No exceptions, nothing. Why is this happenning?** I have been stuck here for two weeks.

Here is my code, this is the snipped from the class A that is fired when event X happens:

```
private TimerEventHandler timerClickingWLRef;
private uint timerIdSeating = 0;
...
        private void launchMultiMedia()
    {
        try
        {
            timerRef = new TimerEventHandler(CheckMultiMedia);
            timerId = timeSetEvent(10, 5, timerRef, UIntPtr.Zero, TIME_KILL_SYNCHRONOUS | TIME_PERIODIC);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }
        stopwatch.Start();          
    }


private void CheckMultiMedia(uint id, uint msg, UIntPtr userCtx, UIntPtr uIntPtr, UIntPtr intPtr)
        {
//This part of the code is no longer reached after a bit
            if (IsWindow(h))
            {
            try
            {
                // Must be initialize to false in order to work
                acquiredLock = false;

                System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(syncThreadsC, ref acquiredLock);
                if (acquiredLock && continue)
                {
                    if (boolvar)
                    {
                        if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 31000) 
                        {
                            // Do sth very fast
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            StopMultiMedia();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (acquiredLockCheck)
                    System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(syncThreadsC);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            StopMultiMedia();
        }
    }
```

In order to avoid a `NullReferenceException` when deleting the object, I have implemented a dispose pattern:

```
public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed)
            return;

        // Free any unmanaged objects here.
        if (timerId != 0)
        {
            timeKillEvent(timerId);
            timerId = 0;
        }

        disposed = true;

        if (disposing)
        {
            // Free any other managed objects here.
        }
    }

    ~ClassA()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
```

I don't understand why it starts working well and then, randomly (it seems after application been a bit busy firing these events, but never more than 5-6 at the same time) it stops firing. I can see `LaunchMultimedia`() is called and `StopWatch.Start()` starts working, however, `the callback function` is not called anymore.

Is there any kind of limitation or similar that prevents the multimedia timer to be fired again at all?

I don't know where to look with no exceptions, warning or errors in the code.

With the information I have I can only assume code is not that important but some condition affecting on it.

If you need more code just let me know.

Comment: _"I can only assume code is not that important"_ -- on Stack Overflow, that's almost always a false assumption. And is definitely false here. You need to debug your problem enough to narrow the problem down to [the _minimum_ amount of _complete_ code required](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem, and provide that minimal, complete code example here. "Stops working" could be "disabled" or "deadlocked" or any number of other things. I will note that even with multimedia timers, there's no guarantee of executing arbitrary code "within ms" of an event occurring.

Comment: Well, I narrowed it as much as possible: I realized the callback function stops being called eventually. I have written console.writelines before and after it, but the callback function is never called but see no mistake in the code. I know sometimes ms can take longer than 10 (in this example). But one thing is to take longer and the other one to not fire at all after certain time even though it does reach this point.

Comment: It behaves as it would have crashed the unmanaged code but VS doesn't catch/show anything and goes on with the rest of the execution without problems.
The minimal complete code I have is the one above. When I said code is not that important is because I can't see wrong stuff when using it, feels like there's some kind of limitation

Comment: I have been done more testing:
If many things can fire the event X (note: this only happens sometimes, like once per minute or two) it fails. However, when I only have 1-2 things that can fire the event, it works.

I'm using wndproc to fire event. Sometimes I receive an event X. I check whether I want to process that or not (calling multimedia timer). If so, I create an object and call multimediatimer.

Having many opportunities to fire the event doesn't imply having the same amount of objects. They are only created when I need multimedia timer. I don't understand why performance goes down

Comment: Mmmm... I have 3 timers working from the beginning at 10ms, checking windows. The more windows I have, the longer this takes, the less chance I have that the OS is able to fire new threads. I believe this is the anwer to the problem: too many low interval timers preventing the application to launch new ones. Will test tomorrow and see if I'm right.